# Transformers: The Dark of the moon - Optimus and The Ark

Tags: transformers, optimus-prime

In *Dark of the moon*, in the beginning we see what looks unmistakeably Optimus's face in the wreck of The Ark when the Apollo astronauts are investigating the wreck site !
[image]

Then how is it that later in the film he says

> "I watched it escape Cybertron myself."

Then how can he be ON The Ark if he watched it escape the planet?

Comment: It's pretty clear he's *not* on the ship, as he investigates the ship IIRC

Comment: I was talking about the 1960's scene, not the present day scene. The scene where the astronauts are investigating the wreck site.

Comment: Ahhhh...right. I don't think it's him, though. Maybe just looks like him (to be honest, it doesn't look totally like him anyway, just a little similar)

Comment: I don't think it looks like him, to be honest.

Comment: That is not Optimus Prime. For brevity's sake, let's say it's Ultra Magnus.

Comment: How can you say that ! Look at that face-plate... How many other Transformers have you seen sporting THAT face plate ? or those extension on the sides of the head... You simply cannot deny that it looks atleast a little like Prime.

Answer (score 6):

It is much more likely that you've spotted an Autobot in its [protoform](http://transformers.wikia.com/wiki/Protoform) state.

In the movie continuity, all Autobots share the same protoform design (the Decepticons share a different design).

[image: Autobot Protoform mode]

As TF Wiki explains

> In the rare case they are not actively practicing their natural proclivity for chameleon-like disguise (usually only when engaged in interstellar travel), Transformers shed their exo-structure and return to their protoform state. This protoform is capable of transforming into its transition form: an armored, cometary shape capable of interstellar travel. Upon landing on a new world and transforming back into a protoform, the Transformer immediately begins trans-scanning for new alternate forms to adopt. When one is chosen, the protoform draws on its own ultra-dense substance and any extraneous matter nearby to generate a new exostructure disguise.

Comment: Ugh. Horrible design is still just... horrible.

Answer (score 1):

Are you mistaking optimus prime for sentinal prime ?
![sentinal in the ark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfphN.jpg)

Comment: NO. This is in no way similar to the one in the image before.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Optimus, that guy is Roller, an action figure sold with the Ark toy!

[Roller](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Roller_(IDW)) appeared in the cartoon and was also spotted in the videogame [Transformers: War for Cybertron,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_War_for_Cybertron) as a lieutenant of Zeta Prime (the game version of Sentinel).

I think that Sentinel left him at the control desk and he died in the crash.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Valorum like The Chancellor?

Answer (score -2):

According to me this is just a mere cybertronian, which is a little like the helmet of Optimus Prime if you look at the classic G1 series will find that a lot of Transformers are like this, they are extraterrestrial robots, and as organisms  they can sometimes be a family or a single, like Ultra Magnus, who is also quite similar to  Optimus